# .htaccess works like i created a new directory

Tags: .htaccess, url-rewriting

I have `bone.php` and `bone.css` inside `public_html` in my server. Inside bone.php i have a link tag which calls bone.css `<link rel="stylesheet" type="text/css"  href="bone.css">`. i have created .htaccess file for `bone.php` file

```
 RewriteRule ^community/([0-9a-zA-Z]+) bone.php?first=$1 [NC, L]
```

After i created .htaccess i need to change link tag like `<link rel="stylesheet" type="text/css"  href="../bone.css">`. Which means `bone.php` thinks its inside a folder, which is not.

If its only way i need change all links inside my website. I hope someone will say there is an another way.Thanks

Comment: `bone.php` doesn't think it's inside a folder, but your browser does, because your URL is indistinguishable from an actual folder. Some misguided soul will probably answer suggesting using a `base` element; don't listen to them. The best way would be to use an absolute URL: `/bone.css` (or `/assets/bone.css` or wherever you'll put your final CSS file)

Comment: So there is no way to change this thing easily? someone sai i sould use `RewriteCond`? anything about that?

Comment: Is changing `bone.css` to `/bone.css` not easy enough?

Comment: Well, that's a natural consequence of your pages now being in a different directory - at least where the browser is concerned. There is no good way to fix it using a RewriteRule. Fixing the links is the best way, IMO.

Answer (score 0):

This is because your relative URIs have their base changed. Originally, the base is `/` when the page is `/bone.php`, and the browser properly fills in relative links with the `/` base. But when the browser goes to a page like `/community/foo/` the base suddenly becomes `/community/foo/` and it tries to append that in front of all relative URLs and thus none of them load.

You can either make your links absolute, or change the URI base in the header of your pages (inbetween the `<head> </head>` tags):

```
<base href="/">
```

Comment: Even if my RewriteRule has no base `RewriteRule ([0-9a-zA-Z]+) bone.php?first=$1 [NC, L]` The links need to change. I think this problem is different than what you thought.

Comment: No, he understood the problem perfectly. It's much better to fix the links and make them absolute than using a base tag, though.